# How can I check with a command line tool if a file exists on a remote FTP server?

Tags: command-line, command, ftp

There is an FTP server where there is a directory in which images reside. There are numerous images (approximately 10000 images). When I try to check it with Total Commander, for example, it cannot read the entirety of the files. So, I cannot be sure if my PHP script really uploaded the file to the server or not.

Is there any surefire solution to check? Perhaps some kind of command-line tool? Thank you.

Comment: What kind of access do you have? Ftp only? Does the check need to be done over FTP?

Comment: Check if `curl` or `wget` can do what you need.

Comment: I have FTP access only.

Comment: Can't you just `GET` the file? Will that work? If it is there, you will manage to download it and, if it isn't, you'll get an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "GET"? curl GET request? Isn't it same as a http request for the image in the browser? Because it does not work. I check it with an image surely exists in the directory but it gave me 404.

Comment: I use Linux and windows alongside. So if anybody mentions curl I get it as a linux command

Comment: Note that you asked your question on a site for "Unix & Linux", so Windows is off-topic here. Both `curl` and `wget` are available for Windows as well, and both can be used for FTP protocol. Please check the documentation. https://everything.curl.dev/ftp or https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/FTP-Options.html

Comment: @TamásBern don't understand that comment. Minimal own research yields that curl works on windows, Linux, AmigaOS, MacOS, HPUX, MS-DOS, Minix, Solaris, Plan9, OS/2, SCO UNIX, Hurd, Haiku, BeOS…

Comment: Ok, sry. I get all the things. With an easy wget -l --ftp-user=<user> --ftp-password='<pass>' ftp://IP/DIR/FILE I could check the existence of files. Thy for the good advices!